# How to convince Visual Studio to use ADB for android dev over TCP/IP

Tags: windows, adb, visual-studio-cordova

So this might be a bit of an edge case, but I'm using visual studio on a VM, and I have my phone in my hand. I'd like to set things up that when I press "play" in visual studio, it compiles my cordova app, and pushes it to my phone next to me, so I can test and debug etc.

My phone is 'rooted' and I have installed ADB wifi. I am able to connect to it from Visual Studio's adb version and also adb devices lists it.

```
 (output from cmd.exe running as Admin in the solution folder)

 C:\Stuff\Code\svn\myapp\MyApp>adb connect 10.10.10.6
 already connected to 10.10.10.6:5555

 C:\Stuff\Code\svn\myapp\MyApp>adb devices
 List of devices attached
 10.10.10.6:5555 device
```

When I press Play in Visual Studio it compiles and gets to the point where it needs to deploy to the phone and then it comes up with the following error: **The system cannot find the file specified**

```
(output from "output" tab in visual studio)

C:/Stuff/Code/svn/myapp/myApp/platforms/android/build/outputs    /apk/android-debug.apk
No scripts found for hook "after_build".
No scripts found for hook "after_compile".
------ Copying back to project: android
2>------ Deploy started: Project: MyApp, Configuration: Debug Android     ------
2>  Querying ADB for attached devices...
2>The system cannot find the file specified
2>The system cannot find the file specified
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: why the downvote? surely there are other people that have the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue and this worked for me...

---

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `adb tcpip 5555`
3. `adb connect 10.10.10.6`
4. `adb devices` - should show your device
5. `Open Visual Studio as Admin`
6. `Type: ALT+B, R (ALT+B then R) to rebuild your solution`
7. `Run your app`

[image]