# New Visual Studio 2019 Install Keystore Issues?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have purchased and set up a new computer to be used for app development using Xamarin. The app was working fine and deployable to Google and Apple stores without issue. Since setting up the new computer, I haven't been able to publish to Google Play. I am guessing the reason revolves around the keystore which has been verified as copied to the same locations. It seems like copying it will not suffice, but it would need to be regenerated. Does anyone have advice on setting up a new system for existing app development on VS2019 and Xamarin?

Comment: you should be able to copy and import the keystore file.  I've done this many times.  You may want to use keytool on both systems to verify that you can open the keyfile, etc.  If you use the wrong key Google should give you a pretty specific error about signing with the wrong key.

Comment: Hi , which version of the Vistual Studio ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Comment: It seems that I was incorrect on the source of the problem. The keystore exists in the correct directory and the app compiles properly. The error is when deploying to an Android device. Complete details are: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  ADB1000:  Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.RequiresUninstallException: The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.
at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName) in ...\Mono.AndroidTools\Internal\AdbOutputParsing.cs:line 339

Comment: Well, that was easy. Change the package name and it deploys. Since the app is using ads there are other issues with that solution. Next step is to use adb for a complete uninstall per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735522/cant-deploy-to-real-android-device-xamarin